# Webview is not reload in Samsung s7 Android

Tags: android

In my code Webview is not reload when in Samsung S7 Device only.
Any help is must appriciatable.How to reload in All device??

```
    web.clearHistory();
    web.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
    web.loadData(getHtmlString(), "text/html", null);
    web.reload();
    web.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2d2b35"));
```

Comment: Are you sure that error is phone related? Have you tried with other phones of different android versions?

Comment: yes, I tested all other devices. error occcurs after change my sdk 19 to 26

Comment: yes same problem with me..